# Error when import BoM.csv in Openerp

Tags: csv, odoo

I create BoM from Excel and then I import to CSV. But when I import the file into Openerp and validate, I get this error:

> ValidateError Error occurred while validating the field(s) product_id: BoM line product should not be same as BoM product

Answer (score 1):

This issue come from the same `product` given in `Bill of Material.`

When you make `Bill of Material` for a `product,` you need to give different product in product and it's component.

For example =>

`product name = Laptop Customized`

and it's component like `USB, Keyboard`

In your case, you given same product in `product name` and `it's component` make it different.

So update the excel sheet and give proper relationship to `Bill of Material` and it's components after than your work will be done.

Comment: if you follow the properly configuration than it must be work.